# Simple query in controller not getting updated results

Tags: postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a very strange issue where I am querying the database for the last result however it is showing the last result from some time in the past.  This database is updated each hour via rake tasks however it doesn't seem that the query is being rerun but instead somehow cached?  Its only happening on Heroku and now when I run it from my local which suggests that it may have something to do with my environment config.  To make things stranger, if I reset the deployed database and push the content back into it the query pulls the right data however then becomes stale again... Any ideas?  Is it caching on the database?

Update:  The query is `input = IonitTankInput.last`

It works just fine on my local however not on production where it instead is grabbing the last record the database was aware of days ago and doesn't recheck for the latest new "last" record added via rake tasks...If I run the query directly on the heroku rails console it returns the correct newly added last record.  No idea what's causing this.

To make things stranger, this query is working on a different page as intended.

UPDATE:  Ok I fixed it however the solution makes no sense unless someone can explain it.  I changed the action from:

```
def show
  @tank = IonitTank.find(params[:id])
  if something
    return false
  end
  @input = @tank.ionit_tank_inputs.last
end
```

To:

```
def show
  @tank = IonitTank.find(params[:id])
  @input = @tank.ionit_tank_inputs.last
  if something
    blah blah
  end
end
```

What is odd is that the if statement wasnt returning false so I know @input was being defined but for some reason it needed to be defined before the if statement is even checked...

Comment: can you share the query that you are using? `User.last`

Comment: do you know if you are using elastic search or something else? is the content of the page cache with `aws cloud front`? and the query is never run

Comment: Nope this is all solely hosted on heroku.

Comment: can you share some light on how the rake is doing the import? there might be something there

Comment: Thanks all for helping, I had to move some code around an if statement however it still shouldnt have impacted this...thanks guys

Comment: glad I was able to help :) happy hacking